# Change data duration to seconds from format d h m s in power bi or power query

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I Have raw data duration , where the format is not standard like this
[image]

i want to convert from Column "Down" to column "inSEC" using this query to manage the d=86400 seconds, h=3600seconds , m =60 seconds

```
inSEC = SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(Report[Down],"d","*86400"),"h","*3600"),"m","*60"),"s","*1")," ","+")
```

and i want to the query automaticly calculate the "multiply" and "add"

example in 31d = 31*86400 = 2,678,400 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Got this answer from someone

```
        DOWN_InSEC = 
    SUMX (
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            DATATABLE (
                "n", STRING,
                "f", INTEGER,
                {
                    { "d", 86400 },
                    { "h", 3600 },
                    { "m", 60 },
                    { "s", 1 }
                }
            ),
            "@sec",
                VAR _p =
                   SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE (
                        SUBSTITUTE (
                            SUBSTITUTE (
                                MID ( 'Report'[Down], 1, FIND ( [n], 'Report'[Down],, 1 ) - 1 ),
                                "m",
                                "|"
                            ),
                            "h",
                            "|"
                        ),
                        "d",
                        "|"
                    )," ","")
                RETURN
                    VALUE ( 0 & PATHITEM ( _p, PATHLENGTH ( _p ) ) ) * [f]
        ),
        [@sec]
)
```

its automaticly calculated the value of seconds

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for either Power BI or Power Query, here is a Power Query solution:

- Split the Down Column on the space

  - Split each of these splits on transition from digit to non-digit
  - Accumulate the sum of seconds by applying the proper multiplier depending on the value of the "non-digit"

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMihWitVBp4wNU1Bok1wFE4tiGNPUEMI0NAUKQ5mWuQrG5lDNGQomprlgpkWGgilUBZAJVg9SFAsA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Down = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Down", type text}}),
    #"Add Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "InSEC", each 
        let 
            #"Split Down" = List.Transform(Text.Split([Down]," "), (l)=>
                Splitter.SplitTextByCharacterTransition({"0".."9"}, (c) => not List.Contains({"0".."9"}, c))(l)),
            
            #"To Sec" = List.Accumulate(#"Split Down",0, (state, current)=>
                    if current{1} = "s" then state + Number.From(current{0})
                        else if current{1} = "m" then state + Number.From(current{0})*60
                        else if current{1} = "h" then state + Number.From(current{0})*3600 
                        else if current{1}="d" then state + Number.From(current{0})*86400
                        else state)
        in 
            #"To Sec", Int64.Type)
in
    #"Add Column"
```

[image]